# Single quote in NSPredicate causing crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, string, predicate

I looked all the similar questions on the web but nothing turned useful to me. I have a string which I receive from server i.e.

'Justin Timberlake - Can't Stop the Feeling'

It has single quotes in it. Before passing it to NSPredicates, it gets changed to

"text = \'\'Justin Timberlake - Can\'t Stop the Feeling\'\'"

I tried everything, i.e. replacing single quote with \' etc. But nothing helped. What else should I do.

Comment: Please share your code, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the string you get from the server has a single quote already in it ("Can't"). To make it work in a predicate you need to use substitution:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text = %@", "Justin Timberlake - Can't Stop the Feeling")
```